Langchain Open AI model error for llama index for Agentic RAG
I need your help on fixing the error of this matter.
I am building agentic RAG via Langchain and Lamma Index, but I have an following error:
## When I use llm = LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35)##

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[47], line 4
      1 from llama_index.core.agent import FunctionCallingAgentWorker
      2 from llama_index.core.agent import AgentRunner
----> 4 agent_worker = FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(tool_retriever=query_engine,
      5                                                      llm=llm,
      6                                                      system_prompt="""You are an agent designed to answer queries over a set of given papers.
      7                                                      Please always use the tools provided to answer a question.Do not rely on prior knowledge.""",
      8                                                      verbose=True)
      9 agent = AgentRunner(agent_worker)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/llm_basic/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/agent/function_calling/step.py:125, in FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(cls, tools, tool_retriever, llm, verbose, max_function_calls, callback_manager, system_prompt, prefix_messages, **kwargs)
    121     prefix_messages = [ChatMessage(content=system_prompt, role="system")]
    123 prefix_messages = prefix_messages or []
--> 125 return cls(
    126     tools=tools,
    127     tool_retriever=tool_retriever,
    128     llm=llm,
    129     prefix_messages=prefix_messages,
    130     verbose=verbose,
    131     max_function_calls=max_function_calls,
    132     callback_manager=callback_manager,
    133     **kwargs,
    134 )

File ~/.pyenv/versions/llm_basic/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/agent/function_calling/step.py:70, in FunctionCallingAgentWorker.__init__(self, tools, llm, prefix_messages, verbose, max_function_calls, callback_manager, tool_retriever, allow_parallel_tool_calls)
     67 """Init params."""
     68 if not llm.metadata.is_function_calling_model:
     69     raise ValueError(
---> 70         f"Model name {llm.model} does not support function calling API. "
     71     )
     72 self._llm = llm
     73 self._verbose = verbose

AttributeError: 'LangChainLLM' object has no attribute 'model'

## When I use llm = LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35.bind_functions(functions=lc_functions))##
llm must be instance of LangChain BaseLanguageModel

When I use llm as llm = LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35) or LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35.bind_functions(functions=lc_functions)), both have errors. Here is the llama index LangChainLLM works in

https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/1bde70b75ee5b4e6a5bc8c1c3f95eaa0dd889ab0/llama-index-legacy/llama_index/legacy/llms/langchain.py#L28

and this is how FunctionCallingAgentWorker works:

https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/blob/1bde70b75ee5b4e6a5bc8c1c3f95eaa0dd889ab0/llama-index-core/llama_index/core/agent/function_calling/step.py

I am referring to Deeplearning course: https://s172-31-8-94p32933.lab-aws-production.deeplearning.ai/notebooks/L3_Building_an_Agent_Reasoning_Loop.ipynb
from llama_index.core.agent import FunctionCallingAgentWorker
from llama_index.core.agent import AgentRunner
from src import custom_langchain
from llama_index.core import Settings
from llama_index.llms.langchain import LangChainLLM

custom_lc_obj  = custom_langchain.CustomLangchain(api_key=pack_api_key)
lc_llm_35 = custom_lc_obj.azure_chat_openai(model_name="gpt-35-turbo", api_version="2024-02-15-preview", metadata={"is_function_calling_model": True}, model_param={"temp": 0, "presence_penalty": 0.1, "top_p": 0.98})
llm = LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35.bind(...)) or LangChainLLM(llm=lc_llm_35)

Settings.llm = llm
Settings.embed_model = embedding

agent_worker = FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tools(tool_retriever=query_engine,
                                                     llm=llm,
                                                     system_prompt="""You are an agent designed to answer queries over a set of given papers.
                                                     Please always use the tools provided to answer a question.Do not rely on prior knowledge.""",
                                                     verbose=True)
agent = AgentRunner(agent_worker)

##custom_langchain.py##
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import requests
import json
import ssl
import httpx
import os
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI

class CustomLangchain:
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        load_dotenv()
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.headers = { "X-Api-Key": self.api_key }
        self.wmt_ca_path = os.getenv("wmt_ca_path")
        self.context = ssl.create_default_context()
        self.context.load_verify_locations(self.wmt_ca_path)
        self.api_key_client = httpx.Client(verify=self.context, headers=self.headers)

    def get_api_client(self):
        return self.api_key_client
    
    def azure_chat_openai(self, model_name, api_version, metadata, model_param, azure_endpoint="https://wmtllmgateway.stage.walmart.com/wmtllmgateway"):
        lc_llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
            openai_api_key=self.api_key,
            model=model_name,
            api_version=api_version,
            azure_endpoint=azure_endpoint,
            http_client=self.api_key_client,
            metadata=metadata,
            temperature=model_param["temp"],
            model_kwargs={"presence_penalty": model_param["presence_penalty"], "top_p": model_param["top_p"]}
        )
        return lc_llm


am limited options and have to use Langchain AzureChatOpenAI().
##requirements.txt##
openai==1.13.3
requests
httpx==0.27.0
python-dotenv
docarray
langchain
pypdf
unstructured==0.6.7
langchain-openai==0.1.0
faiss-cpu
pandas
pymilvus==2.4.0
pypdf2
pdf2image
pdfplumber
langchain_experimental
azure-identity
PyMuPDF==1.24.2
streamlit
lark-parser
scikit-learn
llama-index-llms-langchain
llama-index-vector-stores-milvus

I am expecting to have no error with agentic RAG performance with FunctionCallingAgentWorker.from_tool() function by using LangChainLLM().

I need to set the llm.metadata.is_function_calling_model=True to pass the if condition, but this way does not work and I would like to know how to set llm.metadata.is_function_calling_model=True.

Please see this error:
69     raise ValueError(
---> 70         f"Model name {llm.model} does not support function calling API. "

     71     )

